# How to get URL from the sentence which have text

Tags: selenium

How to get only URL(i.e http://news.co/2h5tgDs?AppId=Watchable&ShareFrom=Twitter&DeviceId=b8cfbdab-327f-4545-bb8b-1c5942e5d2da ) from below Sentence.

Feed-Worthy from @newsNow http://news.co/2h5tgDs?AppId=Watchable&ShareFrom=Twitter&DeviceId=b8cfbdab-327f-4545-bb8b-1c5942e5d2da.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: use regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

if you use python, you can use regex library.
else you can find regular expression library in you own language.

here is expression

```
(http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?
```

Comment: Which language do you use?